# error con laravel y php

Tags: php, laravel-5

en realidad el problema era el laravel pero ahora me da otro ya cambie la clave ya le configure en el .env pero sigue que mas puede pasar; este es el mensaje q me da ahora .

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from users where email =
>   jk@logex.ec limit 1)"

Comment: el error, es que no se puede conectar a la base de datos, verifica que tu db este creada

Comment: Cuando modificas el archivo `.env` tienes que volver a crear tu cache, en tu archivo `.env` deja los datos necesarios para conectarte a la `BD` y después ejecuta el comando `php artisan config:cache` para que tu nueva configuración se actualice en la `cache`.

Answer (score 1):

Limpia la cache de tu proyecto:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache
```